# Reload UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reload

I'm a new programmer in Objective-C and I have a terrible problem in my first application.

I have one class called `Places` (`NSObject`) where I found places in a Google places and return an `NSArray`.

I have another classe called `DisplayPlaces` (`UiViewController`). This class imports my "Place.h".

In my `viewDidLoad` I have this code:

```
Places *places = [[Places alloc]init];

[places.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[places LoadPlaces:places.locationManager.location];
[places.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

[places release];
```

In my method `LoadPlaces` I load JSON URL and put a result in `NSDictionary` after I get only places and put in `NSArray` and return.

Into my `Places` I alloc my `DisplayPlaces` and call a method `ReturnPlaces: NSArray` to return places that I found.

```
- (void)ReturnPlaces:(NSArray *)locais{
    placesArray = locais;
    [self.UITableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [placesArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIndentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier] autorelease];
    }   

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = [placesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

It all works.

My problem is:

In my `ReturnPlaces: NSArray` I call `[MyUiTableView reloadData]` but I can't refresh my UiTableView.

What can I do?

Comment: did set the delegate for the tableview?

Comment: If you set breakpoints in `numberOfRowsInSection:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` does the program reach them? If it doesn't you probably didn't set the delegate. If it does, are the outputs what you expect? (`numberOfRowsInSection` returns the right count etc.)

Comment: What's the property you're using for referencing the `UITableView`? Did you set it's data source and delegate? Also, nowadays using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and then checking if the cell is `nil` is obsolete, just use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` and it will do it all for you.

Answer (score 1):

Set your tableview `yourTableView` as your property and use

```
self.yourTableView = tableView; // for assigning the tableView contents to your property
```

if you are reloading inside any method for tableView, just use

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

if you are reloading outside your tableView methods, use

```
[self.yourTableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling reloadData on the instance of your tableView. In other words if you have

```
MyUITableView *mytableView;
```

then reloading it would require you call

```
[mytableView reloadData];
```

not

```
[MyUITableView reloadData];
```